# How to run openCV algorithms in real-time on Raspberry PI3

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, opencv3.0

I'm working on a Raspberry PI, an embedded linux platform with Raspbian Jessie where Python 2.7 is already installed, and I have OpenCV algorithms that must run in real-time and must apply several HAAR Cascade classifiers on the same image. Is there any method to reduce the time of these operations? such as multithreading for example?

I also hear about GPU calculations but I didn't know from where I can start.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Real-time? Would you mind to update your post with fact about what are your **`CV_image.dtype`**, **`CV_image.shape`** and what is your RPi / process control-loop stability threshold target -- R/T-loop-maxRoundTripTime [ms]? Thanks.

Comment: haar cascade classifier detection methods typically are quite expensive. If your images or max object sizes aren't tiny, I doubt you'll even be able to run a single cascade classifier in "real-time" on a raspberry pi 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you should consider the following:

1. Reduce image size to the minimum required size for recognizing the target object for each classifier. If different objects require different resolutions, you can even use a set of copies of the original image, with different sizes.
2. Identify search regions for each classifier and thereby reduce the search area. For example, if you are searching for face landmarks, you can define search regions for the left eye, right eye, nose, and mouth after running the face detector and finding the rectangle that contains the face.

I am not very sure if optimization is going to be very helpful, because OpenCv already does some hardware optimization.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCv with OpenCL](http://opencv.org/platforms/opencl.html) for parallel processing can be of use to you, as raspberry pi 3 is Quad core. I do not think GPU that comes with these boards are enough powerful. You can try Qualcomm's DSP to computer vision and Neural Network. Nvidia's Tegra GPUs are another option.

Comment: With all due respect, **have you actually run any of promoted solutions in a real-time mode on RPi? If yes, with what `.dtype`-s, `.shape`-s & what was your R/T-loop-maxRTT [ms] + openCV image-processing-pipeline** (a list of function calls) **?**

Comment: How do you define realtime in few milliseconds, 10s of ms, 100s of ms, 1000s of ms OR FPS? RPi is not meant for matrix operations and hence some dimensions needs to be done before picking RPi. Any specific reasons? Simple feature tracking on my i7 mac book consumes 100s of seconds

Comment: Sorry typo I meant milliseconds on my mac book

Comment: Yes, I know well about actual CV processing latencies on airport PTZ-image streams' CV/ML/AI-pipelines. The point for RT systems is not an accumulated latency per-se, but a stability of the SUT [System-Under-Test] Control-Loop. Thus the C/L-RTT [Round-Trip-Time] must meet a certain threshold, if the control-theory is to guarrantee the SUT to operate inside a stability-zone ( remain under control, i.e. not diverging alongside any of unstable/divergent system-dynamics trajectories, i.e. fails and becomes not only flawed, but also dangerous ). Without RTT[{ms|us}] no one can decide about RTT-C/Ls